# Set Relative Hyperlink to open windows explorer using Actions in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2, hyperlink, file-path

I am wondering how to solve this problem I am having. I am trying to make an action in QGIS when I click on my feature, windows explorer will display the folder for that feature. I have the folder name in the attribute column, and an absolute path to the top level of the folder in the Actions.

I have looked up how to hyperlink in QGIS and have looked on the forums, but I have not been able to find a good solution to my questions. I have tried the eVis plugin and it is not a solution I am looking for. I want specifically windows explorer to open when using action on a feature, which is set using relative path.

I hope the screen capture shows up, but if not...
In Layer Properties - Feature|Actions, the Type is set to Windows, the name is Folder, the action is recorded as:
explorer C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TN\Test\Picture[%"Hyperlink"%]

How would I get the recorded action set to a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Answer (score 5):

You can open a relative path. The path will be relative to the project's folder. If you want to check which is the project's folder path, just add an action with: `explorer .`, where `.` stands for the current folder.

To solve your problem, it dependes how do you store the relative path.

If your attribute values already starts with `.`, like `.\GIS DataBase` you simple add an action with:

`explorer [% "PATH" %]`

If your attribute values start with the folder or filename, simple add the string `.\` before the actual path, like:

`explorer ".\"[% "PATH" %]`

[image: Action to open relative path]